# How would I make an animation player for the player once they press on what the proximity prompt

Tags: lua, roblox

I want the player to be able to press on the proximity prompt and not be able to move to play an animation. and remove a specific item from the players backpack called "ID" I thought the script was going to play the animation. Make the player stand still. And remove what the ID. But give back the ID once you play the animation again.

```
local proximityPrompt = script.Parent -- assume the proximity prompt is a child of the script
local animation = script:WaitForChild("Dance")

proximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
    local humanoid = player.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    local dance = humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
    dance:Play()
    dance.Looped = false
end)

local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local backpacks = {}

local ID = "ID"

local function onPromptTriggered(player)
    local playerId = player.UserId
    local backpack = player.Backpack
    local equippedTool = player.Character and player.Character:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Tool")

    if equippedTool and equippedTool.Name == ID then
        equippedTool.Parent = backpack
    end

    if not backpack:FindFirstChild(ID) then
        local storedItems = backpacks[playerId]
        if storedItems then
            local phone = storedItems:FindFirstChild(ID)
            if phone then
                phone.Parent = backpack
            end
        end
    else
        local storedItems = Instance.new("Folder", ServerStorage)
        storedItems.Name = playerId

        for i, tool in pairs(backpack:GetChildren()) do
            if tool.Name == ID then
                tool.Parent = storedItems
            end
        end

        backpacks[playerId] = storedItems
    end
end

script.Parent.Triggered:Connect(onPromptTriggered)

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    backpacks[player.UserId] = Instance.new("Folder", ServerStorage)
    backpacks[player.UserId].Name = player.UserId
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    if backpacks[player.UserId] then
        backpacks[player.UserId]:Destroy()
        backpacks[player.UserId] = nil
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you need to change is this part of your code:

```
proximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
    local humanoid = player.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    local dance = humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
    dance:Play()
    dance.Looped = false
end)
```

**First solution is**:

```
local isPlaying = false
proximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
    local humanoid = player.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    local dance = humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
    local originalWalkSpeed = humanoid.WalkSpeed
    local originalJumpPower = humanoid.JumpPower
    local originalJumpHeight = humanoid.JumpHeight
    
    if not isPlaying then
        dance:Play()
        dance.Looped = false

        humanoid.WalkSpeed = 0
        humanoid.JumpPower = 0
        humanoid.JumpHeight = 0
    
        isPlaying = true
    end

    dance.Ended:Connect(function()
        humanoid.WalkSpeed = originalWalkSpeed
        humanoid.JumpPower = originalJumpPower
        humanoid.JumpHeight = originalJumpHeight
        
        isPlaying = false
    end)
end)
```

here I create variable "isPlaying". In function I remember the original walk speed, the original jump power and the original jump height, then I check if the animation is not playing so player can't play the animation when the animation is already playing, if animation is not playing, I play the animation and set the walk speed, jump power and jump height to zero so the player can't move, also I set "isPlaying" variable to "true". When animation is ended, I set the player walk speed, jump power and jump height to original ones and set "isPlaying" variable to "false"

**Second solution is**:

```
local isPlaying = false
proximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
    local humanoidRootPart = player.Character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
    local humanoid = player.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    local dance = humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)

    if not isPlaying then
        dance:Play()
        dance.Looped = false

        humanoidRootPart.Anchored = true
        isPlaying = true
    end

    dance.Ended:Connect(function()
        humanoidRootPart.Anchored = false
        isPlaying = false
    end)
end)
```

here I create variable "isPlaying". In function I check if the animation is not playing so player can't play the animation when the animation is already playing, if animation is not playing, I play the animation and anchor player's "HumanoidRootPart" so the player can't move, also I set "isPlaying" variable to "true". When animation is ended, I unanchor player's "HumanoidRootPart" and set "isPlaying" variable to "false"

## Differences:

In **first solution** if you jump and trigger proximity prompt in air, you will fall.

In **second solution** if you jump and trigger proximity prompt in air, you will freeze in air.